# How can I add a horizontal scrollbar to a VBA ListBox

Tags: vba

I'd like to add a horizontal scrollbar to a VBA ListBox.

It appears that the built in ListBox does not add a horizontal scrollbar automatically.  I have a number of fields whose contents exceed the width of the ListBox and are thus unreadable to the user.

I found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192184), however the code fails, due to accessing hwnd of the ListBox (which is apparently not available in VBA).  I'd rather not write a native DLL to accomplish this as I suspect there is a better way.

Any idea on how I can add a horizontal scrollbar to a VBA ListBox?

I'm open to the idea of using an alternate control rather than getting it to work with the ListBox specifically.

Comment: Oh, this was so long ago.  I was doing this in Excel iirc, but it's been overcome by events.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try ColumnWidths property?
I have listbox with horizontal scroll bar. I just had to add ColumnWidths property.

For example I have

m`e.Listbox1.Columnwidts ="0.5 in;0.2 in;1.5 in;0.75 in;0.5 in"`

Answer (score 4):

Access will automatically add a horizontal scrollbar if the  column width exceed the width of the listbox. HOWEVER, if you are using multiple columns, the first column cannot be set to 0. You must have at least some value in there, even if it's just 0.1" Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, a VBA listbox will automatically gain a horizontal scrollbar  if the total of its `ColumnWidths` property exceeds its own width.

There are no properties I know of that affect this behaviour, i.e. I don't otherwise know how to force or disable display of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Good and easy to implement answer. When the control is dropped on the form, some people forget to adjust the width, as a result it displays in full. One has to go back and set the size to what they want.

Answer (score 0):

In that article, the only reason it's getting ScaleMode is to set the width of the horizontal scroll bar. You don't have to do that.

```
SendMessageByNum List1.hwnd, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, 800, 0
```

where 800 is the pixel width you want the list box to be able to scroll right to.

You will still need the hWnd. Best bet there is to use an external DLL (written in VB) which can enum through child windows of your process until it finds the windows class for the listbox (you will need to find some way to uniquely identify its parent, such as the window title/text or something). That same DLL could also do the SendMessage call above to set the horizontal text extent (perhaps also it could measure the width of the contained list items).

Answer (score 0):

Handle to he list box can be obtained as follows :-

Dim ListHwnd As Integer
lstboxName.SetFocus
ListHwnd = GetFocus()

Use this ListHwnd as the first parameter to the sendmessage function...

We need to provide the declaration below,Since GetFocus function is not present in VBA by default

Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32" () As Integer

Answer (score 0):

VBA listbox have inbuilt scroll bar, but they will only get activated when there is large amount of data added to them.

Now to manually activate this horizontal scrollbar, you can simply edit the Column-Widths in the property window of that particular list box.
Just set the Column Width to a higher value say 300 and Re-Run the userform

Found this solution in this article
https://envisioncad.com/horizontal-scrolling-on-list-box-controls/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7B3N.png)

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2017, you can click on the list box, then go to the properties panel, and then (scroll down to) find the 'HorizontailScrollbar' property. By default this is property is set to false, so you should set it to true.

You know you have set the scroll bar properly when a small triangle appears in the top right corner of the list box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: VBA is not VB.net, a Visual studio answer doesnt help for MS Office.