# Missing Properties in VBA

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

Im trying to add a horizontal scrollbar to a listbox in a userform in VBA,
since i am displaying a bunch of very long Strings on a VBA Userform and part of the information is not shown. 
Even though the Listbox method .HorizontalScrollBar is listed on the microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/03991dft(v=vs.110)
i dont have the method, when compiling (check first image) i get an error that the .HorizontalScrollbar method is missing

I am also missing the Backstyle-Option for all my userforms (check other image, i think it should be after "BackColor"), is there some stuff i have to activate or download to get these methods? Thanks for your Help!

Horizontal Scrollbar method not found:
[image: Horizontal Scrollbar method not found]

BackStyle not there:

[image: BackStyle not there]

Comment: That documentation applies to VSTO so for use from .Net with Windows Forms, its not the ListBox available to Excel VBA - which as you have discovered supports neither property.  You should explain what it is you want to do with the ListBox.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I would like to have a horizontal Scroll Bar since the Strings i add to the Listbox are really long and currently only a part of the information is shown. I also want a transparent BackStyle of my userform so i can layer a GUI-like image above it.

Comment: A VBA listbox will automatically gain a horizontal scrollbar if the total of its ColumnWidths property exceeds its own width. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/838625/1467082)

Comment: You can add an image to a UserForm but if you have any specific problems implementing that, I'd suggest asking a new question that's specific to *that* problem, since the answer to *this* question is: you're looking at the wrong object model :)

Comment: Thanks, i only have one column, i want to display one long String per row, maybe listbox isnt even the right tool choosen here, i dont know what to set for the Column Width Property since i dont know the length of each String, but it can be a 1000+  chars long. Basically i just want to display a list of very long Strings on a Userform (each row a new String).

Comment: You don't need to know the length of the string. Just force the `ListBox1.ColumnWidths` to a value(s) that sum to *greater than* `ListBox1.Width`. You can do this in the form's `Initialize` event.

Comment: Cool, that solved my Problem, thanks very much. Im totally new here, i dont even know how to upvote your answers